# How to detect bad execution plans automatically?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I want to automate a way to detect when a stored procedure plan changed for worse. I am planning to do it using a list of critical SPs and checking when their plans changed. Then compare the execution metrics with the previous executions collected in extended events.

Does anyone have any recommendations to monitor plans without using a lot of server resources?

Comment: Do you need to know the plans?  Or just the fact that they changed?  Is it sufficient to know that the query is much less (or much more) efficient on one day than another?  Or do you only want to look for cases where the plan changed?

Comment: I would like capture the plan, recompile the SP and alert me. Is not common that this happens but usually is caused by bad statistics or edge case of parameters sniffing.

Comment: 2016 has the query store that would help for this https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/the-sql-server-2016-query-store-built-in-reporting/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had that problem for only on query: 
1. Scheduled job was looking in query cache for particular query.
2. When query is found it looked for `bad` pattern in plan. For instance: Index Seek for index XYZ.
3. If `bad` pattern is found, that query will be automatically deleted from query cache by it's `plan-handle` using `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`